# Adding a letter into a cell

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to add a letter into a cell. I am making a matching game and before I try to make it so a letter is randomly implemented into the cell I would like to know how to just put a letter in a cell when the page loads, even if it is preset and not random. So at the current moment I have 12 cells (12 tds) and I want to make it so when you click one of these cells it will show the letter that is in that cell. Would anybody know how I would start to go about this? The code I have so far is in a jsfiddle, even though it is not much I just want to show you what I mean. As you can see I am trying to match letters up

Thanks

What I would like to know is how, when I click on one of the green cells, I can make a letter appear in the box out of one of the letters in my array I provided

http://jsfiddle.net/6c9qg845/

```
var letters = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F"];


<table>
<tr>
    <td id="cell1"></td>
    <td id="cell2"></td>
    <td id="cell3"></td>
    <td id="cell4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="cell5"></td>
    <td id="cell6"></td>
    <td id="cell7"></td>
    <td id="cell8"></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="cell9"></td>
    <td id="cell10"></td>
    <td id="cell11"></td>
    <td id="cell12"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Now theres a question; thanks! And thanks for not insulting me in the comments or anything...

Comment: My keen powers of perception detect that there was some drama here...

Comment: Yeah, thanks for deleting all of that, it's not like it was something useful or answer-like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend giving your table cells numbers from 0 to 11 to indicate which letter from the array they should get. You can use a `data-` attribute for this:

```
<td data-cell="0"></td>
<td data-cell="1"></td>
```

Then you can use a shuffling algorithm to shuffle the array of letters before the game starts:

```
function swap(array, pos1, pos2) {
    var temp = array[pos1];
    array[pos1] = array[pos2];
    array[pos2] = temp;
}

// Fisher-Yates shuffle
function shuffle(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        var swapPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        swap(array, i, swapPos);
    }
}

shuffle(letters);
```

Lastly, you can give the table an ID, and set up event delegation to handle the click events on the table cells:

```
document.getElementById("board").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var target = e.target,
        cellNo;

    if (target && target.tagName === "TD") {
        cellNo = target.getAttribute("data-cell");
        target.className = "revealed";
        target.textContent = letters[cellNo];
    }
});
```

(And also add some CSS to vertically center the text and change the color of the cell when its class changes).

---

### The result:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var letters = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F"];

    function swap(array, pos1, pos2) {
        var temp = array[pos1];
        array[pos1] = array[pos2];
        array[pos2] = temp;
    }

    // Fisher-Yates shuffle
    function shuffle(array) {
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
            var swapPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
            swap(array, i, swapPos);
        }
    }

    shuffle(letters);

    document.getElementById("board").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var target = e.target,
            cellNo;

        if (target && target.tagName === "TD") {
            cellNo = target.getAttribute("data-cell");
            target.className = "revealed";
            target.textContent = letters[cellNo];
        }
    });
};
```

```css
td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 24pt;
}
td.revealed {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="board">
    <tr>
        <td data-cell="0"></td>
        <td data-cell="1"></td>
        <td data-cell="2"></td>
        <td data-cell="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-cell="4"></td>
        <td data-cell="5"></td>
        <td data-cell="6"></td>
        <td data-cell="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-cell="8"></td>
        <td data-cell="9"></td>
        <td data-cell="10"></td>
        <td data-cell="11"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27kxe8gd/2/

Comment: Hey I just wanted to thank you. Sorry it took so long to get back here. This is a great help. This was an assignment for my class and I tried my best and got a pass! With this I can finally come back to it for some extra practice in Javascript, thanks for helping it make a lot more sense and explaining it

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're doing, but it seems there are 2 options that might help:

1. Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6c9qg845/6/) - select a random letter each time a square is clicked and display it:

   `letters = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F"];
   $('td').click(function() {
     rn = Math.round(Math.random()* 12);
     $(this).html(letters[rn]);
              });`
2. Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6c9qg845/8/). If the letters are pre-set but not visible, you can just change the opacity or color on click, so that the text is either transparent (opacity 0) or opaque (opacity 1); or its color is switched between the same as the background an something different:

   `$('td').click(function() {
     $(this).css('color', 'black');
                });`

Comment: This question isn't tagged with "jquery".

Answer (score 0):

Trying to reconstruct the wiped comment section.

Here is the latest code with the commented lines:

```js
var letters = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F"];
    
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');          // fetch all td elements
    
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {              // loop through them
        tds[i].addEventListener('click', function () {  // add a click listener to each of them
            if (this.textContent == '') {               // check if cell is empty
                var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length); // if so, get a random index
                this.textContent = letters[index];      // and assign it to the cell
                this.className = 'clicked';             // change the class
            }
        })
    }
```

```css
td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}

td.clicked {
    background-color: white;
}
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell1"></td>
        <td id="cell2"></td>
        <td id="cell3"></td>
        <td id="cell4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell5"></td>
        <td id="cell6"></td>
        <td id="cell7"></td>
        <td id="cell8"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell9"></td>
        <td id="cell10"></td>
        <td id="cell11"></td>
        <td id="cell12"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6c9qg845/5/

---

I remember you mentioned you wanted to check for pairs, in that case you need to keep track of every "turn" and compare values of the first and the second cell `if (t1 === t2)`.

---

### UPDATE

Here's a slightly modified, more realistic version of the game:

```js
var letters = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F"];

var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  var t = tds[i];
  if (t.textContent == '') {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
    t.textContent = letters.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(letters); // notice how splice modifies the array so that all the elements are used exactly once
  }
  //})
}

var turn = 0; // can be used better later, for now used just for keeping track of t1 and t2
var t1, t2;   // tiles

// setup clicks
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.className != '') {
      return false; // it has to be a "playable" cell, refuse clicks otherwise
    }
    if (turn % 2 == 0) {  // first tile
      t1 = this;
      this.className = 'clicked';
    } else {              // second tile
      t2 = this;
      this.className = 'clicked';
      setTimeout(function() {   // slight timeout, just looks nicer
        if (t1.textContent == t2.textContent) {     // see if they match
          //alert('it\'s a match!');
          t1.className = t2.className = 'matched';  // assign them this class if they do
        } else {                                    // otherwise

          //alert('no match...');
          t1.className = t2.className = '';         // reset classes

        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    turn++;   // increment turn number (this could easily be a boolean)
  })
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
td.clicked {
  background-color: white;
}

td.matched {
  background-color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="cell1"></td>
    <td id="cell2"></td>
    <td id="cell3"></td>
    <td id="cell4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cell5"></td>
    <td id="cell6"></td>
    <td id="cell7"></td>
    <td id="cell8"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cell9"></td>
    <td id="cell10"></td>
    <td id="cell11"></td>
    <td id="cell12"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There's still a lot of work on this one: the notion of players, optimizing the code (moving parts into functions, I gave you a pretty raw version, trying to stick with the original code), preventing various ways of breaking the game (such as rapid clicking on tiles), etc. All this should be more than enough to get you started.